# 2 4-bit binary multiplication in excel

Tags: vba, excel, bit, multiplication

Using excel to demonstrate 4-bit x 4-bit binary multiplication as follows:

1. Convert the multiplier to binary and process one bit at a time
2. All other operations can be done in decimal.

I have the above question for homework, but it has been given to me by a poor teacher with poor notes. Can anyone give me an idea of where I can read up on the topic? Are there any books (or preferably a link to a webpage) that I could read up on to help me with it?

[image]

This is what I have so far. Obviously it's wrong. The thing I'm having trouble with is the addition of the products. I can't simply use =sum() because it 1+1 should equal '0' with a carry. How do I go about achieving this?

Any advice welcome. Thanking you in advance.
Joe.

Comment: You should try to describe what you have done so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: @assylias, OP updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the addition as you correctly point out - but it's wrong in all the calculated cells and not just the cell you highlighted it's just luck that it's the only place you add 1+1.

So, lets work that through with an example that adds a pair of 4-bit binary numbers together in rows 1 & 2.  There's an interim calculation to put in row 3 and we'll put the result in row 4.

The least significant bit is simplest and we can restrict this to base 2 (binary) using the `MOD` function like this `=MOD(D1+D2,2)` which adds the bits from D1 and D2 and returns 0 where the binary result is 0 or 10 and 1 where it is 1 or 11.

Next we can consider the overflow (or carry) from the less significant operation into the next one...

We can calculate if a bit has overflowed by calculating the integer result of a division by 2.  You can calculate the overflow from column D into `D3` with `=INT((D1+D2)/2)` and we can fill that across.

Finally we integrate the carry with the addition, so in `C3` we can use `=MOD(C1+C2+D3,2)` and again fill that back.

Using this you should be able to see how the binary addition works as Excel formulas and work out why your sheet isn't behaving as you expected.  Here's the whole calculation in one...

```
A                   B                   C                   D

1                   1                   1                   1
1                   1                   1                   1
=INT((A1+A2)/2)     =INT((B1+B2)/2)     =INT((C1+C2)/2)     =INT((D1+D2)/2)
=MOD(A1+A2+B3,2)    =MOD(B1+B2+C3,2)    =MOD(C1+C2+D3,2)    =MOD(D1+D2,2)
```

Comment: I understand that it's wrong in all the cells I was just using it to highlight my predicament! Thank you for this input.